# How to use environment variables using Vite, React and Netlify?

Tags: reactjs, vite, netlify

I'm trying to deploy a page on Netlify using environment variables.
In any component, I try to render the key in two ways that I found available

```js
<p>{import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY}</p>
<p>%VITE_API_GOOGLE%</p>
```

**On localhost only the first way works**

Before starting the deployment I defined both variables in the control panel with the same name that I called in the app - VITE_API_KEY and VITE_API_GOOGLE - but without success.
I built the app using Vite, React, and JS.

I hoped the first way worked

Comment: They are not replaced or have a wrong value?

Comment: I carefully set the keys to be the same in the component, and the values are just for test

Comment: If your api key is not meant to be shared or the key is secret. I recommend you to not bundle the api key.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if that's it but it worked.
I am using class component, when I passed the `import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY` out of component it worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).